# React Hook "useState" is called in function that is neither a React function | Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm having the problem with calling useState hook in my component.
Everything is working fine. I can define props on Container as well as on Continer.Element.

But when I'm trying to call Hooks inside Container.Element - I'm getting an error.

```
const Container: React.FC<Props> & {Element: React.FC<ElementProps>} = () => {
  return <Container.Element />
}

Container.Element = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  return <div>Some JSX code</div>
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I advise you to create a real component for your element.

Comment: The HTML in your JSX is invalid, you have an opening `<b>` tag, but a closing `</div>` tag. Tags need to match

Comment: @Jayce444 Even if tags are good, the rules of hooks aren't respected here. Container.Element is not a valid React Component

Comment: @Jayce444 That was typo really, I simplified the example from my code for the question here.

Comment: @AlexWayne the one in the title. UseState is called in function... But already know what was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `Container` is a valid React component but not the `Container.Element`.

When you do `Container.Element = () => {};`: You are just declaring a js function that return some jsx called `Element`.

To use react hooks, you have to follow the rules of hooks :D

From the react docs :

```
Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. 
Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. 
By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called 
in the same order each time a component renders. 

That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state 
of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. 
(If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Only Call Hooks from React Functions
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code.
```

If you need to use hook in your example, you will have to use it in the `Container` component.

```
const Container: React.FC<Props> & {Element: React.FC<ElementProps>} = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  return <Container.Element />
}

Container.Element = () => {
  return <div>Some JSX code</div>
}
```

Comment: That's interesting didn't know that. I remeber i was working on the project where this type of approach was used. There were App component App.Student, App.Tutor. Each of them had their own state. Everything was working fine, but in typescript I wasn't been able to do this type of approach. Appreciate your answer.